# Voip application crash on iphone during opening blutooth

Tags: ios4

In normal scenario my VOIP application is working fine but when I try to open blue booth, VOIP application is crashing in AudioUnitRender. Use case:

1. Make a normal audio call--audio will come on ear phone
2. Press Home button

   1. Voip will go in background-
3. Make blueTooth on-audio should go on blue tooth
4. Make BT off voice should go on ear phone mod-

If I continuously repeat this use case application is crashing in capture call back and crash is showing in AudioUnitRender.

Crash:

```
Thread 7 name:  AURemoteIO::IOThread
Thread 7 Crashed:
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3497bbf0 memcpy$VARIANT$CortexA8 + 696
1   AudioToolbox                    0x3382a7e6 AUMethodRender(void*, unsigned long*, AudioTimeStamp const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, AudioBufferList*) + 46
2   AudioToolbox                    0x3373d264 AudioUnitRender + 44
3   aVVoIPApp                       0x0001cb58 0x1000 + 113496
4   AudioToolbox                    0x33806cee AUIOHelper::NotifyInputAvailable(AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long, AudioBufferList const&) + 58
5   AudioToolbox                    0x337f707e AURemoteIO::PerformIO(unsigned int, unsigned int, XAudioTimeStamp const&, XAudioTimeStamp const&, int&) + 834
6   AudioToolbox                    0x337f7168 AURIOCallbackReceiver_PerformIO + 40
7   AudioToolbox                    0x337ecf42 _XPerformIO + 178
8   AudioToolbox                    0x33755d64 mshMIGPerform + 112
9   AudioToolbox                    0x337c0742 MSHMIGDispatchMessage + 22
10  AudioToolbox                    0x337f67f8 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Run() + 36
11  AudioToolbox                    0x337fc342 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Entry(void*) + 2
12  AudioToolbox                    0x3373148a CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 138
13  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3494530a _pthread_start + 242
14  libsystem_c.dylib               0x34946bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 7 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x04a4c000    r1: 0x04842040      r2: 0x00000080      r3: 0xfffffd00
    r4: 0x002f399c    r5: 0x3382a7b9      r6: 0x06a00c2c      r7: 0x06a00b90
    r8: 0x06a00cbc    r9: 0x00002000     r10: 0x00000001     r11: 0x007bc013
    ip: 0x04a4c000    sp: 0x06a00a70      lr: 0x3373d483      pc: 0x3497bbf0
  cpsr: 0x20000030
```